# How do I make the GROUP BY clause in this query run?

Tags: sql

Write a SELECT statement that returns three columns:

`EmailAddress`, `OrderID`, and the `order total` for each `customer`.

To do this, you can group the result set by the `EmailAddress` and `OrderID` columns.

In addition, you must calculate the order total from the columns in the `OrderItems` table.

```
SELECT c.EmailAddress, oi.OrderID, (oi.ItemPrice * oi.Quantity) - 
oi.DiscountAmount
FROM Customers c JOIN Orders o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
                 JOIN OrderItems oi ON o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
GROUP BY c.EmailAddress, oi.OrderID
```

Comment: Is this an assignment?

Comment: It was yes, but it was due last Thursday night.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `GROUP BY` and `SUM()`:

```
SELECT c.EmailAddress, oi.OrderID,
       SUM(oi.ItemPrice * oi.Quantity - oi.DiscountAmount)
FROM Customers c JOIN
     Orders o
     ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID JOIN
     OrderItems oi
     ON o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
GROUP BY c.EmailAddress, oi.OrderID;
```

Comment: I've never seen an algorithm like `x * y - z` surrounded by SUM() in order to make it a single line function before. It seems weird to me because I'm not adding anything. Are you just using SUM() because it makes it an single line output?

Comment: @AustinVB . . . No.  I'm saying it because the multiple items in an order need to be summarized on one line.

Comment: And the default for that is to use SUM()? Can something else be used?

Answer (score 0):

Column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function. Your column

```
(oi.ItemPrice * oi.Quantity) - oi.DiscountAmount
```

does not satisfy this requirement. I assume what you want to do is

```
sum((oi.ItemPrice * oi.Quantity) - oi.DiscountAmount)
```

?

Comment: I've never seen an algorithm like `x * y - z` surrounded by SUM() in order to make it a single line function before. It seems weird to me because I'm not adding anything. Are you just using SUM() because it makes it an single line output?